# using classes with constructor objects

Tags: typescript, constructor, axios

I am trying use a class with a constructor object, in another class. But how do I call that class correctly? eg: How do i use Class 1, in Class 2?

The example below is creating an object, from a response from an axios call. The `_object` should be whatever I get from `getData()`. Im not sure if this is the right approach. But how do i then call this class with the constructor, in another class? Ideally I want to be able to query the properties of the object, and use them in the other class, but Im not sure how to call the class properly.

Class 1:

```
export class MyClass {

    private _object: any;

    constructor(object: any) {
        this._object = object;
    }

    public static async getData() {
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    public static async getCurrentData() {
        return new MyClass(await this.getData());
    }

}
```

Trying to use this in another class, with constructor object:

Class 2:

```
new MyClass(object);  // cannot find name object
```

or

```
new MyClass();  // without constuctor object, Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. An argument for 'object' was not provided.'
```

Ive asked related question here:
[return properties of constructor object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725579/return-properties-of-constructor-object/56725608#56725608)

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what you're asking here. But two notes: 1. The error `cannot find name object` means that you haven't defined the identifier `object` anywhere in your code. 2. Your class should be called `MyClass`, not `myClass`. Although you can use any naming you want in your own code, of course, when asking for help it's best to stick to standard naming practices. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, my question then is: how do I use a class with a constructor object in another class?

Comment: You just do. There's nothing special about it. Again: The error is about `object`, not `myClass`/`MyClass`.

Comment: If you quote the entire error (at least, this is what the playground says): *"Cannot find name 'object'. Did you mean 'Object'?"* So...do you mean `Object` rather than `object`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i understand the error is with object. But how to correctly use the constructor object in the other class?

Comment: The `constructor` method on a class is the thing that is called when you use the `new` operator. I don't think having a separate method to call `new` within the same class is necessarily good design. You should probably call `getData()` inside of the constructor itself and then assign its return value to your object property instead.

Comment: @user6086008 - `MyClass` **is** the constructor object. (Note: Although functions are objects, the idiomatic term is "constructor function" rather than "constructor object.") What do you mean by "use" it other than what you're doing, `new MyClass`? What is the `object` argument for? You're accepting a parameter that you're assigning to `_object` in the class, but never using anywhere. If you were using it, we might have *some* idea what you're trying to do, but...

Comment: @GaryO , so is adding 'Object' the wrong way to construct the object? eg: new MyClass(Object);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor requires an object as its argument. So to construct an object of `MyClass`, you'll need to do something like:

```js
let obj = new MyClass({}) // construct with an empty object as the arg
// or:
let argObj = {a: 123}
let obj = new MyClass(argObj)
```