# return properties from object using constructor function

Tags: typescript, constructor, axios

I have a constructor object that is created from a function, which is the response of a axios `get` request. I then want to return properties of that object and save some of the  values to be used as a string in another class. eg: I want to be able to save values: `response.data.name`, `response.data.address` from the resposne. So far, im getting undefined when trying to get those values.

```
export class MyClass {

    private _myobject: any;

    constructor(myobject: any) {
        this._myobject = myobject;
    }

    public static async getData() {

            return axios.get(url)
                .then(response => response.data)
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    }

    public static async getCurrentData() {
        return new MyClass(await this.getData());

    }

   getName() {
       console.log(this._myobject.name);
       return this._myobject.name;
   }
}
```

other class

```
const temp = new MyClass(Object).getName(); //  undefined
const temp = new MyClass({}).getName(); //  undefined
```

Comment: *"I have a constructor object that is created from a function"* What do you mean by that? Constructors **are** functions, and you don't have any constructors in that code that are *created* by functions.

Comment: Nothing in your code using the class ever calls `getData`. Also note that `getName` is just accessing `name` on the object passed into the constructor, which has nothing whatsoever to do with the data from axios. Given this question and [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724526/using-classes-with-constructor-objects), I think you need to step back from what you're currently doing and work through some basic JavaScript and TypeScript tutorials. The code above doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyClass.getCurrentData() creates a new instance of MyClass, which will contain any fetched data. This data however remains on this instance, it is not static.

Also, I don't see any await calls for the async function getCurrentData, so it can be that it is executed only after you're doing your getName() checks for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was solved as below:

```
export class MyClass {

    private _object: any;

    private constructor(object: any) {
        this._object = object;
    }

    private static async getData() {
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    // returns data from get request, adds to constructor of same class
    public static async getCurrentData() {
        return new MyClass(await MyClass.getData());
    }

    public getName() {  // getter uses constructor
        return this._object.name;
    }
}

export class Artifact {

    public async addDataToReport() {

        const myClass = await MyClass.getCurrentData(); //  create new instance of MyClass
        const name = myClass.getName(); // call getter from myClass

        console.log(name);
    }
}
```